# Standard text in the body of your posts

Tags: sharepoint-designer, post

Is there a way of when creating a 'Post' when you click on 'create' there is a standard format already in the body of your post?

I have to keep copying and pasting into the body and wonder if there was a quicker way?

The standard format never changes there all topics that need to be commented about.

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Are you using **discussion board** app? You can add default value to your body textarea on the default new form.

Open your list, click "List" tab at the top ribbon banner, select Form Web Parts -> Default New Form:

[image]

In the default new form edit mode view, add a content editor webpart. Click on the webpart area, click **edit source** at ribbon bar. Then insert below script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
var textContent = 'Standard text in the body of your posts';
$('div[id$="TextField_inplacerte"').text(textContent);
});
</script>​​​​​​
```

Comment: No I am using a Blog app - I did try code above and it came up with an error.

Answer (score 1):

I want to piggy-back on Mark's answer and make it work for the blog

- Open http://YOUR_SITE/YOUR_BLOG/Lists/Posts/NewPost.aspx URL.
- Cog wheel > Edit page > add a Web Part > Content Editor Web Part
- Inject the following in the body of the CEWP:

**Code to inject to CEWP:**

```
<script>
    $("[id^='Body_'] p").innerHTML = "<h1>Standard text in the body of your posts!<h1>"
</script>
```

- In Web part properties, Appearance > Chrome Type: **None** to hide the webpart's border
- Save your page and enjoy.

Comment: Yes I believe it should work.